# consolidating vim files in ~/.vim folder

Tags: vim

I'm trying to consolidate all my vim related files/plugins into `~/.vim` folder so that I can dump it on github and get started with pathogen. However, right now all my vim plugins are scattered all over the place.

As an example, the syntax plugin is in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim` and when I run `:scriptnames` this shows up as well since I have `syntax on` in my `.vimrc`.

So for trial, I moved `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax` to `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax1` and copied `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax` to `~/.vim`.

however, now when I start vim it complains that it can't open file `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim` (because I renamed that folder).  I expected vim to automatically now pickup the syntax folder residing in my `~/.vim`.

My runtime path is:

```
~/.vim, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles, /usr/share/vim/vim73, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after, ~/.vim/after, /usr/share/vim/vim73
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Maybe cause it's sourcing the script with `source` instead of `runtime`. I think if you always use `runtime` it will search your runtime path.

Comment: The files in /usr/share/vim are provided by the vim distribution.  There should be no reason to copy those files into your home folder unless you are modifying them yourself.

Comment: @Randy exactly, I realized that after posting the question and that's why voted for it to be closed :)

Comment: Also, check out hashrocket's dotmatrix for some ideas.  It's a nice setup that I've cloned for my personal use.  https://github.com/hashrocket/dotmatrix

Answer (score 4):

Give this a look:

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/

This is what I use and I've not had trouble with any plugins.

Comment: Yup. This is exactly what I use and that's the way to organize vim plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Some special vim scripts (I know only one: `syntax/syntax.vim`) are looked up only in `$VIMRUNTIME` directory (that is by default `/usr/share/vim/vim{major_ver_num}{minor_ver_num}`), not in the whole `&runtimepath`. So you can't do this without setting VIMRUNTIME before running `syntax on`. It does not matter though whether you will set it in something like `~/.zprofile`, use an alias `vim='VIMRUNTIME=~/.vim vim'` or just do `let $VIMRUNTIME=$HOME.'/.vim'`.